# Select Duplicate records in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table below in Oracle

Table1

```
State | Product |other fields
CA    | P1      | xxxx
OR    | P1      | xxxx
OR    | P1      | xxxx
OR    | P1      | xxxx
WA    | P1      | xxxx
VA    | P2      | xxxx
```

My Output should be only select if State has been occurred more than once.

```
State | Product |other fields
OR    | P1      | xxxx
```

Comment: Have you tried anything - such as a select statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to count duplicate states then:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       State,
       Product,
       Other_Fields
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT(1) OVER ( PARTITION BY State ) AS cnt
  FROM   Table1 t
)
WHERE  cnt > 1;
```

If you want to consider duplicate rows (considering all fields) then:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Table1
GROUP BY State, Product, Other_Fields
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select state, product, column_3, column_4
from (
  select state, product, column_3, column_4, 
         count(*) over (partition by state) as cnt
  from the_table
) t
where cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use **ROW_NUMBER** analytic function.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS(
  2  SELECT 'CA' State, 'P1' product FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'OR', 'P1' product from dual union all
  4  SELECT 'OR', 'P1' product FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 'OR', 'P1' product FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 'WA', 'P1' product FROM dual UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 'VA', 'P2' product from dual
  8  )
  9  -- end of sample_data mimicking real table
 10  SELECT distinct state,
 11    product
 12  FROM
 13    (SELECT state,
 14      product,
 15      row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY state ORDER BY product) rn
 16    FROM sample_data
 17    )
 18  WHERE rn >1;

ST PR
-- --
OR P1

SQL>
```